# What does nullable signify for a database

Tags: sql, database, nullable

What is nullable refers for a Database, and what does it signifies ?
nullable = 0
nullable = 1

The Image contains column value of a table where nullable is defined:
[image]

Note : Check the highlighted value in Picture

Comment: The tag wiki for `nullable` should already give you plenty of information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type

Comment: Which DBMS product is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nullable field (marked with 1) is allowed to have `NULL` values. If it is marked with 0, it means that it must have a value inside.

Answer (score 2):

Nullable means it can have a null value, thus not required.

Answer (score 0):

It's a boolean flag to tell if the columns is nullable (aka it can contains null).

If nullable = 1 the column can contains null.

Comment: It means, if a column nullable type is defined as 0, it means it cannot be NULL, every time it will have some value.

Answer (score 0):

It's an additional flag for a database column type which signifies whether or not that column can be set to NULL.